# VNC viewer RFB protocol error: bad desktop size 0x0

Tags: vncserver, vnc-viewer

I'm running VNC server on a baby Fit PC2 computer under Win7 in the loft with no monitor attached. After a restart, my VNC viewer shows the above error and no connection is possible. Attaching a monitor via HDMI (which I can then detach) solves the problem. What do I need to alter to avoid having to climbing into the loft after every reboot?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to plug in an HDMI display emulator like the one in the link below. The PC will think it has a monitor attached to it. I've used a DP version of it on a couple of PCs that run without monitors.

[https://www.amazon.com/Display-Emulator-Compatible-Windows-fit-Headless/dp/B09P6DKF28](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09P6DKF28)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1194645)